# WHERE query inside an AND statement? PHP/PDO/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 tables on my website, a `users` table and a `user_friendships` table each structured as so...

**Users**

```
id  |  user_id  |  credits_bank  |  credits_offered
```

**User Friendships**

```
id  |  user_id  |  user_followed_id
```

When my user logs in he is presented with a list of other users on the website - the list of other users are those who are stored in the `users` table and have a greater value in the `credits_bank` table than that of the `credits_offered` table.

When a friendship is created, the session users `id` is stored in the `user_friendships` table, and the id of the other member he followed is also stored in the `user_friendships` table under the column `user_followed_id`.

The problem is I now need a query to return all users who have move `credits_bank` than `credits_offered` and users that aren't already in the `user_frienships` table in the same record as the session user.

I'm currently using...

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN user_friendships uf ON u.user_id = uf.user_followed_id
WHERE u.user_id <> ? 
    AND u.credits_offered <= credits_bank
    AND uf.user_followed_id IS NULL
```

---

**Update**

I want to see a list of users whose `credits_bank` is a greater value than `credits_offered` and I only want to show them if they dont already exist in a record in my `user_friendships` table in the same row as my session user.

**Users**

```
id  |  user_id  |  credits_bank  |  credits_offered
___________________________________________________
1        123            10                 2
2        231            6                  3
3        312            6                  5
4        213            2                  1
```

**User Friendships**

```
id  |  user_id  |  user_followed_id
___________________________________________________
1       123                231
2       123                312
```

**Result**

If session user_id = 123 then...

```
user_id 231 and 312 WOULDN'T show as they are in the user friendships table alongside session user id
user_id 213 WOULD show as they have more credits_bank than credits_offered and arent in    friendships table
```

IF the session user_id was 312 then he would see all results as he isnt friends with anybody in the user_friendships table...

Comment: What is the query trying to do?

Comment: There can only be one `where` clause, so it is vaguely unclear what you mean.  It seems like you want an `and` clause, but what it should do?  Nobody knows.  Maybe you need to join another table or query before getting to the `where` at all?

Comment: For the best answers, edit your question and paste the CREATE TABLE statements and a few INSERT statements for your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're close. If the user id of the current user is called SESS_USER_ID, something like this should work for you;

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_friendships uf 
   ON uf.user_followed_id = u.user_id 
  AND uf.user_id = SESS_USER_ID
WHERE u.credits_offered <= credits_bank
  AND uf.user_followed_id IS NULL
  AND u.user_id <> SESS_USER_ID
```

(note that SESS_USER_ID is used twice in the query to make it simple)

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24c31/3).

Comment: Still no luck @JoachimIsaksson, I've updated my question with a practical example

Comment: @Liam http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24c31/2, exact same query with your sample data and userid 123. Could you point out what I missed? :)

Comment: This works @Joachim, my only problem now is that it also returns the currently logged in user from the users table :/

Comment: @Liam Updated the query, and the SQLfiddle to remove the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_id, u.credits_bank, u.credits_offered 
FROM users u 
WHERE u.credits_bank>u.credits_offered
    AND u.user_id = [ENTER LOGGED IN USERS ID HERE] 
    AND u.user_id NOT IN (
        SELECT f.user_ol
        FROM user_friendships f 
    )
```

Let me know if you have any issues

**EDIT**
Latest SQL:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_id, u.credits_bank, u.credits_offered 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN user_friendships f 
   ON f.user_followed_id = u.user_id 
       AND u.credits_bank > u.credits_offered 
       AND f.user_id != [CURRENT_USER_ID]
       AND u.user_id != [CURRENT_USER_ID]
```

Comment: Thanks @PhilCross, this just returns all of my users now however

Comment: I've just created a test table with the same structure and SQL, and seems to work fine :-/ You do want to see a list of users who have `credits_bank` greater than `credits_offered` and whos `user_id` is not in the `user_id` of the `friendships` table right?

Comment: Sort of @philcross, apologies I think Ive worded my question incorrectly. The first bit is right that I want to see a list of users who have credits_bank greater than credits_offered, but then I want to see a list of users who isnt already friends with the current user_id in my friendships table. Ill update my question...

Comment: Not a problem @liam I have updated my answer, I think I was nearly there! I'd added a `where` condition, you'll see it look like `[INSERT CURRENT USERS ID HERE]`, this is where you should use the logged in users ID. I think this is right, if not, let me know and i'll have another look

Comment: But no still no luck @PhilCross, still returns all my users :/

Comment: Sorry @liam, I misunderstood your question! I have read your newest edit and understand it better. I've updated my answer (SQL is at the bottom)

Comment: Sorry my answer wasn't correct! Glad you found your answer though!